# Cron Jobs between x and y on weekdays

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I'm trying to set a cron job up to run every ten minutes on weekdays between 9am and 5pm.

I have a bunch of jobs set up now to run on weekdays at 10 minute intervals (so 48 jobs)

Is there a way to do this in one Cron Job?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every 10 minutes between 09:00 - 17:00 on weekdays (monday - friday)

```
*/10 09-17 * * 1-5 /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `*/10 9-17 * * 1-5 [command]`. That will run every 10 minutes, between hours 9 and 17 (12+5), on days 1 through 5 (mon-fri).  See [this page](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs/) for
 a good explanation of how to format cron jobs.